# How to test a simple Angular Reactive Form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-test

I have a Component which contains a very simple Reactive Form, with just one input field and one button to be used to submit the form.

Here the code of the html template

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input type="text" formControlName="idControl">
  <button type="submit" class="button" [disabled]="myForm.invalid">Submit Form</button>
</form>
```

and here the FormGroup within the Component code

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-form',
  templateUrl: './my-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-form.component.scss']
})
export class MyFormComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm = new FormGroup({
    idControl: new FormControl('' , [
      Validators.required
    ])
  });
.....
.....
}
```

Now I want to write a simple test for this Component, a test that basically says

- first set the value of the input field to "Blah"
- then click the button to submit the form
- finally check that, after the click of the button, the value of the
  control named idControl is actually "Blah"

The following test example actually works

```
it('1.1 should update the value of the input field after an "input" event on the input field', () => {
    const inputVal = 'Blah';
    const input = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
    input.value = inputVal;

    input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

    expect(fixture.componentInstance.myForm.value.idControl).toEqual(inputVal);
  });
```

This test though seems to me not to reflect exactly what I want to simulate, which is a click on the button. On the other hand, if I try to actually simulate the click event on the button, I am not able to create a successful test. For instance, the following test does not pass

```
it('1.2 should update the value of the input field after a "submit" event on the form', () => {
    const inputVal = 'Blah1';
    const input = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
    input.value = inputVal;
    const submitEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button'));
    submitEl.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(fixture.componentInstance.myForm.value.idControl).toEqual(inputVal);
  });
```

I have also tried different variants, e.g. using

```
fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button')).nativeElement.click();
```

but nothing seems to work.

This is the test configuration code which I use

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ InputFormComponent],
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(InputFormComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

My question is whether I am missing something about how to test a Form in Angular.

Comment: Quick thought - you may need a `fixture.whenStable().then(() => { fixture.detectChanges();  /* now test */ })` in there to allow the button to render on screen before clicking on it.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution to the initial problem, but I found at least one way to change the value of an input. Instead of

```js
const input = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
input.value = inputVal;
```

try

```js
component.formControl.setValue(inputVal, { emitEvent: true });
```

The `emitEvent` option ensures that not only the value is changed but also it triggers the event as if a user just typed it.

Unfortunately this won't test the binding between template and component.